# Recursive update of a oldvalue to a new value in a nested JSON without knowing the Keypath

Tags: python

I am new to test python and so my question is simple, but I couldn't find an easy way to do this: I have a nested JSON in a file and I need to find a value ( not the Key) and replace it with a new value. Here I do not care about the Key path. I tried reading JSON as String and used string.replace(XXX,newvalue), it worked but it replaced the double quotes with single quotes around the Key value pairs. But I need the JSON string with the new value. 
This is just a sample JSON, but it can as nested as it could be. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
{   "type": "postData",
"data": {
    "postId":"XXX",
    "postTimestamp": "1521543600",
    "pageType": "/home.php:topnews",
    "viewTime": 1521545993647,
    "gender": 3,
    "likes": "8",
    "comments_shares_viewes": ["1"],
    "posters": [{"type": "XXX",
        "id": "695e45affa1e07529ac917f6d573a"} ],
    "postImg": 1,
    "postDesc": [XXX],
    "origLink": 0,
    "duration": 0,
    "timestamp": 1521545993647},
    "back_time": 1521545993693},
        {"type": "saveLooked",
        "data": {
            "duration": 18,
            "timestamp": 1521545993656,
            "sessionId": XXX,
            "gender": 2},
            "back_time": 1521546011657}
```

The Code I tried was:

```
def Construct_JSONString(JString,klist,vlist):
s =   str(JString)
klen=   len(klist)
for i in range(0,klen):
  OldValue=   klist[i] 
  NewValue=   vlist[i]
  s=     s.replace(OldValue, NewValue)
return s
```

Comment: Could you provide your solution with *string.replace*?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
 import json

 new_json_with_replaced_values=json.dumps(your_json).replace("XXX", "newvalue")
```

Comment: I will try this and update results soon. But here is the sample code I used.  I am passing a list of old values and corresponding new values along with JSON. Calling this function from Robot Test Framework.

Comment: user2510479 -  it worked, but this time the / introduced before each double quotes as ESC char.  How to remove them? Also is there any way I can extrarct out all the KEYPATHS from the Json string into a list, and then for each JSONPATH, I can pass a new Value and set dynamically?